# generate pdf file by servlet in a liferay portlet

Tags: servlets, pdf-generation, liferay, itext, portlet

In a liferay portlet I want to use servlet and generate a pdf file as a result.This is my codes that I copied them below.

**view.jsp:**

```
<p style="color:black">
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/pdfServlet">Click here for DownLoad PDF Format!!!</a></p>
```

**my portlet body**

```
public class pdfFormat extends GenericPortlet {

/**
 * Helper method to serve up the mandatory view mode.
 */
protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = getPortletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view.jsp");
    dispatcher.include(request, response);
}
```

}

and my **servlet** code:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Document document = new Document();
    try{
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf");  

    //  FontFactory.register("c:\\WINDOWS\\fonts\\DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf", "MY_FONT");
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("c:\\WINDOWS\\fonts\\DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,true);
        Font font = new Font(baseFont);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());            
        ArrayList<reportModel> ShowResult = new ArrayList<reportModel>();
        reportDAO dao = new reportDAO();
        ShowResult = dao.ShowAllinfo();         
        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            String strTitle = ShowResult.get(i).getTitle();
            String strSite = ShowResult.get(i).getSite();
            String strNote = ShowResult.get(i).getNote();

            document.add(new Paragraph(strTitle,font));
            document.add(new Paragraph(strSite,font));
            document.add(new Paragraph(strNote,font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("****************************************"));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.close();

}
```

---

After that I deploy my portlet and got a pdf file I see this error in my tomcat log file :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [pdfServlet] in context with path [/pdfReport] threw exception [ExceptionConverter: ClientAbortException:  java.net.So
cketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error] with root cause
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:383)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:401)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.flush(OutputStreamCounter.java:89)
        at com.itextpdf.text.DocWriter.close(DocWriter.java:233)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1286)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:810)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
        at com.iran.servlet.pdfServlet.doGet(pdfServlet.java:86)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
        at $Proxy402.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:167)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:95)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:70)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:108)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you considered making a ResourseRequest (portlet 2.0 only) instead? That way you don't need a servlet to  generate a PDF - you can use a controller within your portlet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that pdf writer, but you might want to try to feed it with a document that has already been created? E.g. move `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());` to the end of your method.

Background: The pdfwriter might have already written the (empty) document that you passed into that call.

But this is only a guess - as I said, I'm not familiar with that component